# Pattern matching in UNIX Case statement

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, pattern-matching

I am working with a shell script in which I need to differentiate between **tar.gz**, **gz|bz** etc.

I am first extracting the extension of the file and then trying to match it using `case` and my first case being `*tar*` which is supposed to match files with `tar` in their extension because they can be extracted with the same command.

The problem is the next set of statements where I'm trying to match `gz` `bz2` etc. I need a case pattern which matches `bz` or `gz2` but at the same time also checks that there's no `tar` in the extension.

I'm clueless with shell pattern matching and have written this `[!(tar).*(bz2|bz)$]` (please don't laugh)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `$` is regex syntax, `*tar*` is glob (shell) syntax.
`case` uses glob syntax. In order to use the `!` in glob, you have to enable `extglob`.
Why do you use the brackets ?

Comment: @LaurentG I had no idea how to proceed. Tried to mix regex, failed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`case` processes in order, so if you look for `tar` files first, it should not go to next:

```
case "${word}" in
  *.tar* )
    #process tar
    :;; #break
  *.bz2|*.bz )
    #process bz2 and bz
    :;; #break
  * )
    #default
    :;;
esac
```

Comment: correct, `:` is just the always `true` statement, it's to avoid errors for missing command... not sure it is actually relevant here.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.