# bash script from docker does not work as expected if statement

Tags: bash, docker, curl, alpine-linux

I am using this image which has bash v4.3.48 and curl v7.56.1:

https://hub.docker.com/r/bizongroup/alpine-curl-bash/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated

Inside the docker I write the following script:

```
email_dest="iz@gmail.com}}"
suffix="@gmail.com"
dm_to=${email_dest%"$suffix"}

if [[ $email_dest == *"@users.noreply.github.com"* ]]
then
  echo "Email address is no reply. Please fix your email preferences in Github"
elif [[ $email_dest == *$suffix* ]]
then
  curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"text":"Hello <@'"$dm_to"'>. '{{inputs.parameters.workflow_name}}' "}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/T01JNE5DXA7/B0246T84N75/hHDk7RUg2BWl2bYbPoN9r
else
  echo "Email address is not of digibank domain!"
fi
```

If I run this script with bash command <script_name> it will work as expected (Run the curl command). But if I run it with sh command <script_name> it will not run the curl command:

```
/ # bash send-message.sh
ok/ #  
/ # sh send-message.sh
Email address is not of digibank domain!
```

Any suggestion of what it could be? and what should be changed so it will work with sh?

Comment: Please add a shebang and then paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Are you asking how to remove the bashisms from the script, or how to get sh to execute bash when running this script?

Comment: Probably not related to your current problem but: are you 100% sure you want to use an alpine based image provided by a github group that only produced 2 images and has not updated them once in the last 4 years, knowing you can easilly rebuild that yourself from the official and up-do-date alpine image by just running their [3 lines Dockerfile](https://github.com/bizongroup/alpine-curl-bash/blob/master/Dockerfile)?

Comment: @BMitch I am asking how to get sh to run bash when running this script. Or simpler, when do I need to do in order to run this script as: sh send-message.sh so it will enter the expected "if" and run the curl command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That lies within the [differences between `bash` and `sh`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash):
`sh` is [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) compliant, whereas `bash` isn't (fully).

As a best practice you should always include a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)):

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "this is going to run within bash"
```

With this you can now omit calling the script via `bash myscript` and just call it with `./myscript` and it is always going to use bash (even if you are in a `zsh`, `sh` or whatever else).

However, if you truly want to have a script that runs with both `sh` and `bash` then you should rewrite your script to be plain `sh` compliant (i.e. POSIX).

**TL;DR**

> Any suggestion of what it could be? and what should be changed so it will work with sh?

In your script you are using `bash` extensions such as `[[` which is why it does not work with `sh`.
Checkout the links I posted above for more differences and how you can "convert" your `bash` script into a `sh` script.

The following site has a great summary on what to change in order to get your `bash` script working for `dash` which is an implementation of `sh`: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism

Furthermore, you can also check if any issues exist by using the following site: https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Thanks for the elaborated answer! I added #!usr/bin/env bash and it didnt work. I am struggling with rewriting this script to run with sh. Any chances you can help here?

Comment: @I.zv : As I mentioned start rewriting the script by omitting `bash` extensions. You can check your `sh` script on the following site to get help on what you would need to rewrite: https://www.shellcheck.net/
Start by using only single (`[`) instead of double brackets (`[[`) within your script (see here for the effect: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542832/difference-between-single-and-double-square-brackets-in-bash). That should be sufficient enough to fix your if statements once you remove globs (`*`) and replace `==` with `=` as well.

Comment: You can use the following site for a list of workarounds: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism

Comment: What can I do inside the if statement? I MUST check "if string ends with..." I see it is not possible in shell?

Comment: @I.zv It's completely possible; just [use a `case` statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42813783/pattern-matching-in-unix-case-statement).